# HighCharts heatmap from SQL Query in ASP.NET webForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, highcharts

I am trying to Render a HeatMap chart with dynamic data from an SQL server Database.

the JavaScript below will render the Chart with Static data

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales by Product per Hour'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:30', '15:00']
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Bakery', 'Butchery', 'Haba', 'Bread', 'Others'],
        title: null
    },


    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '**' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '** sold 
**' +
    this.point.value + '** items on 
**' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '**';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per Department',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
            [0, 0, 10],
            [0, 0, 10],
            [0, 1, 19],
            [0, 2, 8],
            [0, 3, 24],
            [0, 4, 67],
            [1, 0, 92],
            [1, 1, 58],
            [1, 2, 78],
            [1, 3, 117],
            [1, 4, 48],
            [2, 0, 35],
            [2, 1, 15],
            [2, 2, 123],
            [2, 3, 64],
            [2, 4, 52],
            [3, 0, 72],
            [3, 1, 132],
            [3, 2, 114],
            [3, 3, 19],
            [3, 4, 16],
            [4, 0, 38],
            [4, 1, 5],
            [4, 2, 8],
            [4, 3, 117],
            [4, 4, 115],
            [5, 0, 88],
            [5, 1, 32],
            [5, 2, 12],
            [5, 3, 6],
            [5, 4, 120],
            [6, 0, 13],
            [6, 1, 44],
            [6, 2, 88],
            [6, 3, 98],
            [6, 4, 96],
            [7, 0, 31],
            [7, 1, 1],
            [7, 2, 82],
            [7, 3, 32],
            [7, 4, 30],
            [8, 0, 85],
            [8, 1, 97],
            [8, 2, 123],
            [8, 3, 64],
            [8, 4, 84],
            [9, 0, 47],
            [9, 1, 114],
            [9, 2, 31],
            [9, 3, 48],
            [9, 4, 91]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]

});

Comment: White space and line breaks in SQL is a must when writing it. Please do take your time to format your code in a readable format,

Comment: You should append the values into the chart configuration using javascript. Try first read the data using ajax then append the values into the chart json